# Uncaught ReferencEerror function is not defined, how to use typeof with an if else?

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I am trying to get the initials (upper case letters) of the name that the user enters inside the text field. I get and error that my function getInitials() is not defined. Why do I get this error? Also I want to check if the function exists with typeof.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Second task HS</title>
</head>

<body>

<form name="myForm" id="eForm" action="#">
<label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="fullname"/><br>
    <input name="button" type="button" value="Pick" onclick="getInitials();"/>

</form>
<div id="result">
</div>

<script type="javascript">

    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value;//I need to stringify       the input and use it!
    var arr, nameArr, first, last;
    nameArr = name.split(' ');
    first = nameArr[0][0].toUpperCase();
    last = nameArr[nameArr.length - 1][0].toUpperCase();
        if(typeof getInitials == 'function'){
        function getInitials(nameArr) {
            return {first: first, last: last};
            }
                getInitials(nameInput);
        }else{
            alert('Check getInitials!');
        }

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you trying to get the name from user in upper case letter?

Comment: Yes and afterwards it picks the first letters. I don't understand why is the function undefined.

Comment: Please have a look my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the text in `<script type="javascript">`, the statement should be like this `<script type="text/javascript">`

Here is the simple version of what you wanted, try it, this program expects first name Or first and last name only.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Second task HS</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var arr, first, last;
function getInitials() {
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value; //I need to stringify 
    nameArr = nameInput.split(' ');
    if(nameArr.length > 1){
        first = nameArr[0].toUpperCase();
        last = nameArr[1].toUpperCase();

    }else{
        first = nameInput.toUpperCase();
    }

    var result = {first: first, last: last};
    alert(result.first);
    alert(result.last);
}   
</script>
</head>

<body>
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="fullname"/><br>
<input name="button" type="button" value="Pick" onclick="getInitials()"/>
<div id="result">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yep I just modified it to give me only the initials with                     first = nameArr[0][0].toUpperCase();
last = nameArr[nameArr.length - 1][0].toUpperCase();

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you are checking if the function exists... before creating it !

Try rather this JS code :

```
function getInitials( nameInput ) {
    var nameArr = nameInput.split(' ');
    return {
       first: nameArr[0][0].toUpperCase(),
       last: nameArr[nameArr.length - 1][0].toUpperCase()
    };
}

function getInitialsFromInput() {
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if(getInitials instanceof Function){ //strictly speaking, useless because it is obviously a function
        alert(getInitials(nameInput));
    }else{
        alert('Check getInitials!');
    }
}

getInitialsFromInput() ;
```

(and use "getInitialsFromInput()" for the onclick to gather the input's value)

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense. `getInitials` Just is not assigned initially, so the inline click handler within the button will never work.

If you need the input value with first characters uppercased and initials, try something like:

```
document.querySelector('button[value=Pick]').onclick = getInitials;

    function getInitials(e) {
    var value =  document.querySelector('#name')
                   .value.split(/\s+/)
                   .map( first2Upper );
    if (value[0].length){
        var ret = {first: value[0], 
                   last: value[1], 
                   initials: value[0][0] +(value[1] && value[1][0] || '')};
        document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = 
            value.join(' ') + ' (initials: '+ret.initials+')';
        return ret;
    } else {
        alert('please enter a value');
    }
}

function first2Upper(str) {
  return str.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1); 
}
```

Here's [**a mockup in jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/FY33u/)

Comment: Wrong, `name.split(' ')[0][0]` will return *first character* of the first array item (or `undefined` if `name` is an empty string). It's the same as `name.split(' ')[0].charAt(0)`.

Comment: The first and the third line are now identical. Is it intentional?

Comment: @Pavlo you should apply for a job as proof reader ;). Thanks, corrected